# How to remove all cut planes when using restoreState in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the restoreState function to set cut planes and it works just fine:

`NOP_VIEWER.restoreState(JSON.parse('{"cutplanes": [[0,0,0,0]]}'));`

But how do I remove the cut planes again? Show all objects do not work and neither do

`NOP_VIEWER.restoreState(JSON.parse('{"cutplanes": []}'));`

or

`NOP_VIEWER.setCutPlanes();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is

```
NOP_VIEWER.restoreState(JSON.parse('{"cutplanes": null}'));
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrille, that helped. I had to put a NOP_VIEWER.showAll(); first, but now it works!

Comment: For viewer v7, `NOP_VIEWER.restoreState(JSON.parse('{"cutplanes": []}'));` should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you have to pass an empty array to setCutPlanes()

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setcutplanes-planes

> Passing an empty list or null is equivalent to setting zero cut planes